# Динамическая вставка символа в строку

Tags: java, android

Добрый день.

Есть андроид приложении, а в нём есть (будет) форма добавления банковской карты и там есть поле под 16-ти знаковое число, cvv-код и срок действия карты формата MM/YY.

Задача состоит в следующем: сделать так чтобы при вводе данных в поле "срок действия" после ввода первых двух цифр автоматически ставился символ "/".

Comment: TextWatcher в помощь

Comment: @iFr0z прав, проверяешь если был 1 символ, а стало 2, то добавляешь слеш, а если было 3, а стало 2, то удаляешь 2-й символ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться интерфейсом `TextWatcher`:

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    int mCountBefore;
    int mCountAfter;
    int mStartNumber;

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        mCountBefore = count;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        mCountAfter = count;
        mStartNumber = start;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (mCountAfter > mCountBefore && mStartNumber == 1) {
            s.append("/");
        } else if (mCountAfter < mCountBefore && mStartNumber == 2) {
            s.delete(s.length()-1, s.length());
        }

        if (s.length() == 6) {
            s.delete(s.length()-1, s.length());
        }
    }
});
```

Здесь реализовано:

- После ввода второй цифры в поле ввода появляется слеш;
- После удаления слеша удаляется вторая цифра;
- Ограничение на формат `MM/YY` по длине.

Также можно реализовать проверку по маске `MM/YY` с помощью, например, регулярных выражений.

Comment: Любезный post_zeew подскажите пожалуйста кой текст филд для этого дела лучше использовать

Comment: @user230778, Это для обычного `EditText`.

Comment: Именно так текст, НО(!) надо чтобы выезжала клавиатурка с цифрами а в поле можно было вводить стринговое значение так как ****** заказчик  хочет что бы был символ "/"

Comment: @user230778, Для этого достаточно добавить `EditText` два атрибута: `android:inputType="number"` и `android:digits="0123456789/"`.

Answer (score 0):

у экземпляра editText вызовите метод addTextChangedListener. Тем самым вы сможете обрабатывать изменение текста.